# VBA Coding to scrape all elements with same HTML structure on single webpage

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

My current code works perfectly to 'scrape' the desired text from the specifc element on the web page:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim ieDoc As Object
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        URL = cel.Value
        With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            .Visible = False
            .Navigate URL

            Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

            Set ieDoc = .Document
            cel.Offset(, 1).Value = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("fsl fwb fcb")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
           .Quit
        End With
    Next cel    
End Sub
```

How would I amend my code to run through all of the elements on the page with the same HTML structure?

Comment: "*page with the same HTML structure?*" hard to tell what you mean, but you need a loop going through that HTML structure. e.g. iterating `i` here `ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("fsl fwb fcb")(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText`. If this is not helpful please [edit] your original question and add a better description of which HTML structure you mean to iterate through.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is that each element on the same page has the same HTML structure, so the Class Name and Tag Name are to stay the same.

Comment: did you even try what I wrote? you won't get a full working solution here without putting some effort in yourself. It is still not clear **which** "*same HTML structure*" you mean. I see no HTML structure here. (1) So first try to implement the suggestion of my first comment and (2) if it doesn't work or you got stuck please [edit] your question and add pretty much more details about the structure you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I havent tried it yet. I was just trying to clear up my question.